# BSD conjecture for abelian schemes and the classical version

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, abelian-schemes

I would like to know the relation between the BSD conjecture for abelian schemes (as stated for example in [T Keller](https://www.timokeller.name)'s thesis) and the clasical BSD conjecture.

In particular, can one state the classical version from the general one..?

Answer (score 2):

The BSD conjecture for an Abelian variety $A$ over, say, a global field $K$ with model $X$ (the spectrum of the ring of integers of $K$ if $K$ is a number field and the smooth projective model of $K$ in the function field case) is (up to some modifications for the infinite places in the number field case) the BSD conjecture for the Néron model $\mathscr{A}/X$.

In https://www.timokeller.name/TateShafarevich.pdf, Theorem 4.4 and 4.5, is the comparison of $Ш(\mathscr{A}/X) := \mathrm{H}^1_\mathrm{et}(X,\mathscr{A})$ with the classical $Ш(A/K)$ defined as a kernel of Galois cohomology groups.

Comment: You asked in your answer (before I edited it) how to create Ш in math formulas on this site. Just putting the Cyrillic letter Ш within a pair of dollar signs does the trick, producing $Ш$.

Comment: @KConrad: How does one "put" that character within a pair of dollar signs if one doesn't have a Cyrillic keyboard? Is there a more robust method?

Comment: @nfdc23, do it by the universal answer to lots of questions: use Wikipedia. Copy and paste a Ш from the Wikipedia page about Shafarevich (his name in Russian appears on the first line), the page about the Tate-Shafarevich group, or the page about the letter Ш itself (google "letter sha" and it should be the first hit).